# Combine two tables, new column sum of older columns

Tags: sql, select, count, db2

Given two separate SQL queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(N.NurseID) AS Nurses, D.DName, D.HName
FROM Department AS D, Nurse_Work AS N
WHERE N.DName = D.DName AND N.HName = D.HName
GROUP BY D.DName, D.HName;

SELECT COUNT(P.PhysicianID) AS Physicians, D.DName, D.HName
FROM Physician AS P, Department AS D
WHERE P.DName = D.DName AND P.HName = D.HName
GROUP BY D.DName, D.HName;
```

I get the following result:

```
SELECT COUNT(N.NurseID) AS Nurses, D.DName, D.HName FROM Department AS D, 
Nurse_Work AS N WHERE N.DName = D.DName AND N.HName = D.HName GROUP BY 
D.DName, D.HName

NURSES      DNAME                                                        HNAME                                                       
----------- -------------------------------- ----------------------------------
      8     General Surgery                                              H1                                  
     10     General Surgery                                              H3
      7     General Surgery                                              H4
     10     General Surgery                                              H5
      7     General Surgery                                              H2                          
      3     Intensive Care Unit                                          H1                                   
      2     Intensive Care Unit                                          H3
      1     Intensive Care Unit                                          H4
      2     Intensive Care Unit                                          H5
      3     Intensive Care Unit                                          H2
      6     Ophthalmology                                                H1                 
      4     Ophthalmology                                                H3
      4     Ophthalmology                                                H4
      2     Ophthalmology                                                H5
      2     Ophthalmology                                                H2
      3     Otolaryngology                                               H1    
      1     Otolaryngology                                               H3
      2     Otolaryngology                                               H4
      2     Otolaryngology                                               H5
      2     Otolaryngology                                               H2
      4     Radiology                                                    H1
      6     Radiology                                                    H3
      4     Radiology                                                    H4
      5     Radiology                                                    H5
      6     Radiology                                                    H2

25 record(s) selected.


SELECT COUNT(P.PhysicianID) AS Physicians, D.DName, D.HName FROM Physician AS 
P, Department AS D WHERE P.DName = D.DName AND P.HName = D.HName GROUP BY 
D.DName, D.HName

PHYSICIANS  DNAME                                                        HNAME                                                       
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
      2 General Surgery                                              H1                              
      2 General Surgery                                              H3
      2 General Surgery                                              H4
      2 General Surgery                                              H5
      2 General Surgery                                              H2
      1 Intensive Care Unit                                          H1                                
      1 Intensive Care Unit                                          H3
      1 Intensive Care Unit                                          H4
      1 Intensive Care Unit                                          H5
      1 Intensive Care Unit                                          H2
      1 Ophthalmology                                                H1                                 
      1 Ophthalmology                                                H3
      1 Ophthalmology                                                H4
      1 Ophthalmology                                                H5
      1 Ophthalmology                                                H2
      1 Otolaryngology                                               H1                           
      1 Otolaryngology                                               H3
      1 Otolaryngology                                               H4
      1 Otolaryngology                                               H5
      1 Otolaryngology                                               H2
      1 Radiology                                                    H1                           
      1 Radiology                                                    H3
      1 Radiology                                                    H4
      1 Radiology                                                    H5
      1 Radiology                                                    H2

25 record(s) selected.
```

My goal is to find the department and its hospital with the most employees (nurses and physicians), I have managed to separately count how many employees by job, now I would like to combine the resultant tables into one where the column on the left is the sum of the nurses and physicians of that respective department/hospital combination. I attempted to use JOIN and UNION however they only seem to give me a resultant table with three columns where one column displays both physicians and nurses together with the values separated instead of summed together. How can I create a table with a column that will sum the count of nurses and physicians of that respective department/hospital combination?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd join a query on the departments' details with two aggregate queries (one on each table), and then add the two counts:

```
SELECT    d.dname, 
          d.hname,
          COALESCE(num_nurses, 0),
          COALESCE(num_physicians, 0),
          COALESCE(num_nurses, 0) + COALESCE(num_physicians, 0) AS total
FROM      department d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   dname, hname, COUNT(*) AS num_nurses
           FROM     nurse_work
           GROUP BY dname, hname) n ON n.dname = d.dname AND n.hname = d.hname
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   dname, hname, COUNT(*) AS num_physicians
           FROM     physician
           GROUP BY dname, hname) p ON p.dname = d.dname AND p.hname = d.hname
```

Comment: Much better than what I was attempting, I guess my thought process was off.

Comment: How can I take the max values in this case? Including ties.

Comment: @TheShield I'd surround it with another query and use `rank` on the counts

Comment: Wouldn't rank only sort them?

Comment: @TheShield you'd then add a condition to only get those with a rank of 1. Comments don't really lend to such explanations, though - could you open a different question for this?

Comment: @Mureinik 
Your query produces wrong results if there is a department with  nurses only or physicians only.
Should be:

`SELECT d.dname, d.hname, coalesce(num_nurses, 0) + coalesce(num_physicians, 0) AS total
FROM   department d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   dname, hname, COUNT(*) AS num_nurses
        FROM     nurse_work
        GROUP BY dname, hname) n ON n.dname = d.dname AND n.hname = d.hname
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   dname, hname, COUNT(*) AS num_physicians
        FROM     physician
        GROUP BY dname, hname) p ON p.dname = d.dname AND p.hname = d.hname`

Comment: @MarkBarinstein good point. Should have used left joins. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used your base query and got that together using UNION ALL since UNION might remove the duplicate if there is same count for nurse and physician in a hospital,then I'm taking the sum of both physicians and nurses.

```
Select DNAME,HName,SUM(CountAll) from
(SELECT COUNT(N.NurseID) AS CountAll, D.DName, D.HName
FROM Department AS D, Nurse_Work AS N
WHERE N.DName = D.DName AND N.HName = D.HName
GROUP BY D.DName, D.HName
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(P.PhysicianID) AS CountAll, D.DName, D.HName
FROM Physician AS P, Department AS D
WHERE P.DName = D.DName AND P.HName = D.HName
GROUP BY D.DName, D.HName)a
GROUP BY DNAME,HName
```